# mvc: Adding values of radio buttons checked into a collection and saving to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with a textbox and some questions with radio buttons. I want users of this form to check each of the radio buttons. It is mandatory. I want to take the values checked whether Yes or No together with the name or Id of each question and write to the database using entity framework.
I can do the writing to the database If I know how to collect this information into a collection.
How can I add these to a collection please?

```
         public class HomeController : Controller
            {
                public ActionResult Index()
                {

                }

                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult ProcessToDb()
                {

                    return View();
                } 
            }

        @using (@Html.BeginForm("ProcessToDb", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        { 
             <h2>My Test</h2>

            <div>Email Address</div>
            <div>
                 @Html.TextBox("EmailAddress", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="question1">Are you ok?</label>
                <input type="radio" name="group1"  value="Yes">Yes
                <input type="radio" name="group1" value="No">No
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="question2">Is the answer correct?</label>
                <input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes">Yes
                <input type="radio" name="group2" value="No">No
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="question3"> Did you overtake him ?</label>
                <input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes">Yes
                <input type="radio" name="group3" value="No">No
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send"> <input type="reset">
            </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start with a view model representing what you want to display/edit, for example

```
public class AnswerVM
{
  public int QuestionID { get; set; }
  public string QuestionText { get; set; }
  public bool Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the GET method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  List<AnswerVM> model = new AnswerVM();
  // populate the collection from the database but for testing purposes
  model.Add(new AnswerVM() { QuestionID = 1, QuestionText = "Are you ok?" });
  model.Add(new AnswerVM() { QuestionID = 2, QuestionText = "Is the answer correct?" });
  return View(model);
}
```

Then in the view

```
@model List<yourAssembly.AnswerVM>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].QuestionID)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].QuestionText)
    <label>
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Answer, true)
      <span>Yes</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Answer, false)
      <span>No</span>
    </label>
  }
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

And the POST method

```
public ActionResult Index(List<AnswerVM> model)
{
  foreach (AnswerVM answer in model)
  {
    // access the QuestionID and Answer properties and save to the database
  }
  // redirect
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will work on this. The radio button should be Yes or No though but I didnt see the No. I saw only yes.

Comment: Thanks a million for all your help.